# Variations Sku not showing up Wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have set up a woocommerce store and I add some variations to some products. Each variation has its own sku number, but for some reason they are not showing up on the products overview panel. Is there any way were I can add them or somebody could show me the right direction to go.
Also, if I try to search the variation, is not showing up the product were is located. Do I have to register the variation sku somewere? Is this comming by default with woocommerce or not?

Thanks!

[image]

This is how I have set up the variations:

[image]

Comment: I think you are using underscore in SKU thats the reason why your products does'nt showing SKU.

Comment: Nop... there are products with _ and they are simple products and they show up.. and there are products with _ and without it, as variable products and they do not show up...

Comment: Requesting question closing [Flag] as its having nothing to deal with code issues. Even person asking is not active on problem replies.

Comment: If you don't know the answer it doesn't mean it's not code related. Found this bug open on githubhttps://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/1734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok given that nobody came with an aswer I had to dig a little bit myself :D 
So here is the solution that I found for the moment.

On file class-wc-admin-post-types.php which is located on woocommerce/includes/admin

You have to modify some code on line 277

```
case 'sku' :

    $type = (get_class($the_product));

    if( $type == 'WC_Product_Variable' ){

        $available_variations = $the_product->get_available_variations();

        echo '<strong> Variations: </strong>' . count($available_variations) . '<br><br>';

        for ($i = 0; $i <  count($available_variations); $i++ ) {

            echo ($available_variations[$i]['sku']) . '<br>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $the_product->get_sku() ? $the_product->get_sku() : '<span class="na">&ndash;</span>';
    }
break;
```

And now you can get something like this:
When you have variations on your product you will show the amount of variations and all of the available sku's and if is not a variable product you will only show the sku.

Now I'm thinking that I will probably modify also the stock colum and show the amount of stock on each one of them.

Hope this helps someone else. And thanks for the ones who tried to help!

[image]

Ok... so I added the support for stock nothing much different than then previous code... So on the same document now on line 344, you can add this.

```
case 'is_in_stock' :

            $type = (get_class($the_product));

            if( $type == 'WC_Product_Variable' ){

                $available_variations = $the_product->get_available_variations();

                echo '<strong> Variations stock: </strong> <br><br>';

                for ($i = 0; $i <  count($available_variations); $i++ ) {


                    if ( $available_variations[$i]['is_in_stock'] == 0 ) {
                        echo '<mark class="outofstock">' . __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
                    }else {

                        echo '<mark class="instock">' . __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';

                    }
                    if ($available_variations[$i]['variation_is_active']) {
                        echo ' &times; ' . $available_variations[$i]['max_qty'] . '<br>' ;
                    }
                }
            } else {

                if ( $the_product->is_in_stock() ) {
                    echo '<mark class="instock">' . __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
                } else {
                    echo '<mark class="outofstock">' . __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</mark>';
                }

                if ( $the_product->managing_stock() ) {
                    echo ' &times; ' . $the_product->get_total_stock() ;

                }
            }
            break;
```

An you get something like this:

[image]

For more information check out link below.
 
Resume: this approach can have some performance problems... carefull on how many product variations do you have.

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/9396

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'dev_designs_show_sku', 5 );
function dev_designs_show_sku(){
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
      for ($i = 0; $i <  count($available_variations); $i++ ) {    
          echo 'SKU: ' . ($available_variations[$i]['sku']) . '<br>';
      }
    } else {
      echo 'SKU: ' . $product->get_sku();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code may answer the OP's question, it is better to include context, or reasoning as to why/how this solves the issue.  This will help future visitors learn from your post and apply it to their own issues, and keeps SO a high value location for finding solutions to programming issues. Please `edit` if you can add some additional info. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the IF conditional check that surround the HTML out of the SKU from the meta.php file. Around LINE 18.

The file is in the WC plugins/templates folder.

OR

Just from `this -> $product->get_sku()` From the IF statement as that is causing the issue.

It returns an empty string is why the IF conditional is never satisfied.

In addition, the reason why this happens is if the parent product does not have a SKU, and only your variables have, this issue will occur. Hence my comment up top stating it returns empty string as it tries to pull from the parent first. another words if you have set SKU to the parent and variables, everything will work even without modification of the code I mentioned.

Comment: the file that you are talking about meta.php is for showing up the sku on the single product view... Im talking abut the backend.. the pictures above. Asyou can see there is only a ku showing up on the single procucts but there is an empty space on the variable products.

Comment: What you have done till now to fix this? I don't think so this is relevant to codding any way. May be you are skipping in installation. As you see our contribution in WooCommerce [https://github.com/dreamyourcareer/woocommerce] we are not facong any issue like that.

Comment: this link is not going anywere

Comment: Its going to WooCommerce Repository, Do you have any idea about how to get help from GitHub or have every used it?